# Error in the implementation of Functor for my datatype

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

When I define following `Functor` for Maybe , it works fine

```
    instance Functor Maybe where
        fmap func Nothing = Nothing
        fmap func (Just val) = Just (func val)
```

I have defined my datatype as:

```
    type Vec2 = (Double, Double)
    data Body = Body Vec2 Vec2 Double (Color3 Double) deriving(Eq,Ord, Show, Foldable)
```

But when I define following `functor` for it:

```
    instance Functor Body where
    fmap func (Body pos vel mass clr) = Body (func pos vel mass clr)
```

I get the following error:

> Expected kind '* -> *', but Body has kind *

Kindly identify what is the issue?

Comment: side note - I would recommend using record syntax for your `Body` data type

Answer (score 6):

`Maybe` is not a type. `Maybe Int, Maybe Char, Maybe String, ...` are types.

`Body` is a type. `Body Int, Body Char, Body String, ...` are nonsense.

In order to be a functor, your `data` must define a parametric type like `Maybe`.

I guess you actually want a regular function rather than a functor instance. I'm not sure, however, about what you are really trying to accomplish.